# What does B"H mean in this question?

Tags: discussion

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10520821/107625), the very first paragraph reads:

> B"H

This is a completely unknown term to me (I'm from Germany).

I've googled it with no success. I'm not even sure it stands for anything.

Since until recently I didn't even know what "[tl;dr](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tl%3Bdr)" means, I've decided to better ask here, just to be sure.

**My question:**

What does the `B"H` in the beginning of the mentioned SO question stand for?

Comment: Given the username, I'm gonna give a wild guess that this is an abbreviation of some Jewish greeting. I've never seen this before, though.

Comment: @Nathan going by that theory - "B'ezrat HaShem" looks feasible which according to wiki is *Used by religious Jews when speaking of the future and wanting God's help (similar to "God willing")*

Comment: User name is the cue, google `hebrew B"H`.  Salutations don't belong in an SO post :)

Comment: The answer you accepted is wrong. Another example of why the "accepted answer" feature in Stack exchange is wrong. A person which obviously doesn't know the answer choose the right answer (or else why would he ask...?). This is ridiculous!

Comment: @gdoron The solution would be to point out why it's wrong in a comment to that answer. Not a brilliant solution, but right now, I don't know if the user accepted another question since you posted this comment, or if the accepted answer is still wrong.

Comment: Restricting the search to Wiktionary, `site:en.wiktionary.org B"H`, would have found it: [B"H](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/B%22H) (though not the very first hit, but the second when I tried it using my favourite search engine).

Comment: @HansPassant *Salutations don't belong in an SO post :)* So then how ironic is it that a question about salutations receives 52 upvotes and 2 fav's on Meta. **If "Salutations don't belong in an SO post", questions about them don't belong on Meta.**

Comment: @HansPassant See here -> http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta. The first sentence reads **Meta Stack Overflow is the part of the site where users discuss the workings and policies of Stack Overflow rather than discussing programming itself.** *Could you or someone else please explain me how *B"H* is related to the *workings and policies of Stack Overflow*? Clearly, either that first sentence (in the link) is unequivocally wrong or this question most definitely does not belong here.

Comment: @SatwikNadkarny - This question belongs on meta because the OP had no way of knowing beforehand that the acronym was a Hebrew phrase and not a term specific to Stack Overflow like FGITW. It'd be silly to expect someone who didn't know what something meant at all to somehow know whether or not it's a term related to SO or programming in general.

Comment: @BSMP *"OP had no way of knowing beforehand that the acronym was a Hebrew phrase and not a term specific to Stack Overflow like FGITW"*. So, that would also qualify acronyms like AFAIK, AKA, BTDT, BTW, FFS, FWIW, FYI, IDK, IMHO etc. You see, it'd be silly to expect someone who didn't know what these acronyms meant at all to somehow know whether or not it's a term related to SO or programming in general. **If you get the gist, this logic can be extended to include anything and everything.**

Comment: @SatwikNadkarny - Yes, that would mean questions on other acronyms, as long as they were used in an SO post, would be on topic. I don't see that as a problem. Whether something should or should not be edited out of a post is on topic on Meta and you can't determine whether something is noise if you don't know what it means. OP, I'm sure you're not really interested in this discussion so I'll leave it at that.

Comment: @tripleee, The accepted answer is still wrong. There is a different answer with the correct answer. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321467/601179 If I'll comment with the correct answer, will it matter? The OP has no idea and no tools to check who is right. This is absurd. ps. I'm religious Jewish.

Comment: @tripleee, just noticed even a better answer was given: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321517/601179

Answer (score 63, accepted):

From http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/606644/jewish/What-does-BH-mean.htm:

> B"H (or BH) is an acronym for the Hebrew words `Baruch Hashem`, which
>   means, `Blessed be God`.
>
> Traditionally, Jewish people begin letters and emails with this
>   acronym,  to contextualize what's most important, and also to remind
>   us that all comes from `Baruch Hashem`— including the contents of the
>   communication to follow.

Comment: I don't want to be rude but I assume we should edit that out, right? As per the guideline: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) where the consensus s: Yes.

Comment: @rene, I was surprised at first nobody edited that out, before realizing the question is from 2012. I don't know if it is worth bumping just to remove three characters.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi only [42 occurrences](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/475691) ... if that isn't the hand of some God ...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: It'll fall off the front page in mere seconds. I edited out the greeting.

Comment: Only note: whilst you are correct about what Baruch Hashem means, It's traditional to put "Be'ezrat Hashem" on corners of documents (with the help of god), not Baruch Hashem. Sauce: mostly growing up as israeli jew but also: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8119

Comment: @rene Following the same reasoning, all the posts starting with "Bismillah", or "Bismillahirrahmanirrahim" should be edited to remove the salutation, right? http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/476607

Comment: @pau.moreno: Right.

Comment: As always context is important. In the context of writing letters or similar it's NOT *Baruch Hashem* (ברוך השם) but ***Be'ezrat Hashem*** (בעזרת השם).

Comment: I personally think B'ezrat Hashem should always be abbreviated בע"ה to prevent confusion

Answer (score 42):

Actually, it's "be'ezrat hashem", which means "with the help of god."
Trust me, though, it doesn't improve the efficiency or the correctness of the code in any way. Feel free to delete it.

Comment: Deleting this term will hurt the writer's feelings...

Comment: @Etgar How can a feeling be hurt? Is this a joke?

Comment: StackOverflow is generally unconcerned with the feelings of people. We care about quality of questions and answers. If there's something irrelevant in a question, get rid of it. Religious sentiments on StackOverflow are irrelevant, unless you're proclaiming Jon Skeet as your god, praise be his name.

Comment: @UweKeim many humans have been known to experience [psychological pain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychological_pain), for which one common term in English is ['hurt feelings'](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/feeling#Noun). HTH.

Comment: @JamesENL: Still noise - you can generally assume that *all* posts are made in reverence of Jon Skeet, there is no need to be explicit about it.

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned in the other answers, B"H stands for [B'ezrat Hashem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Besiyata_Dishmaya#B.27ezrat_Hashem) (בעזרת השם), which is the Hebrew term for "with God's help".

The `H` ("Hashem") actually means "the name", implying the name of God in order to not specifically write the name of the Hebrew God. This makes the expression literally translate to "with the help of the name".

While it is quite reasonable to assume that **it does not belong on SO** and does not contribute to code quality, it **could be a delicate issue**.

The **B"H** (ב"ה) and its equivalent **BS"D** (בס"ד, from Aramic `Besiyata Dishmaya`, with the help  of the heavens, not to be confused with the operating system) acronym is somewhat common among practicing Jews, and a common interpretation is that it signifies that there is something of god in everyday things such as SO questions.

Writing and deleting God's name is an issue among religious Jews.

Deleting God's name (or even related names) from a physical document is considered [disrespectful and even forbidden](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36675/why-are-jews-so-meticulous-about-not-saying-writing-god), and recently the topic of erasing the name from computer monitors or files was discussed by prominent rabbis (rest assured, the rabbis generally **agreed that [it is allowed](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7275/is-it-permissible-to-erase-the-name-of-g-d-from-an-e-reader)**).

The practice is not common among secular Jews and in one case that I am aware of was explicitly forbidden by a secular minister in Israel ([article in Hebrew](http://news.walla.co.il/item/372097)).

Comment: Surely it is "allowed" (if we choose to abide by others' religious rules) to remove it where it is used in a totally inappropriate place?

Comment: @RadLexus, where did I say otherwise? `it does not belong on SO` is right there in my answer (in bold). Since the OP did not know what it meant and why it was written there in the first place, I tried to explain as I happen to live in Israel and know. I also wanted to provide some insight as to why someone might think that putting that phrase at the top of a message was appropriate and discuss the effects of removing it from their point of view. To be clear, **I personally believe that there is no place for it on SO and would delete it if encountered**.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that BS"D *b'siyata dishmaya* literally means "with the help of Heaven", not "with the help of the Name" (*sh'maya* being cognate with Hebrew *shamayim*, not Hebrew *shem*). But yeah, it amounts to the same thing.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I should brush up on my Aramic. Fixed :)

Comment: Where you wrote "Writing and deleting God's name is an issue among religious Jews."   It's a bit misleading. Indeed, the statement is true, but that is why they write Hashem(literally Ha=The Shem=Name) and not a name of God(or even a title in any  language like in English God or Lord, they may hiphenate G-d or L-rd to avoid saying even a title of God).  There can be issues with throwing away pieces of paper in religious judaism(if it's religious material they may bury the paper sometimes), but  it has nothing to do with whether or not there is a B'H on it.

Comment: i.e. where you wrote that line ""Writing and deleting God's name is an issue among religious Jews.""   somebody may read that second part, and think deleting the B'H is an issue of deleting God's name and thus an issue among religious Jews. But it isn't deleting God's name. And so I am pretty sure it's not an issue but you could ask on judaism.stackexchange!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I don't want to dive too deep into it, as this is not the place and I am not that much of an expert, but writing and erasing some of the names is an issue WRT any physically written text, not just religious texts. In fact, one of the explanations for using BS"D over B"H is not to use the letter `ה` which appears it the ineffable name. Anyway, given it is Latin script on a digital medium makes this pretty much a non-issue from a religious standpoint according to current rulings.