# Where should I say thank you on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, answers

The community of Stack Overflow is what makes it such a helpful and powerful resource. I have had many questions answered that I could not find on Google, from professors, etc.

However, I have not found an appropriate place to thank those who answer my questions. It is not advised to say "thank you" in comments, and most definitely not in answers. Is there not an appropriate place to say thank you after someone answers your question, or am I to assume that upvoting and choosing an answer as the best answer should suffice as enough gratitude?

This isn't about how to donate to Stack Overflow or how to thank the website. It's about thanking specific users on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: "or am I to assume that upvoting and choosing an answer as the best answer should suffice as enough gratitude?" Yup, pretty much.

Comment: @rene I'm not asking how to thank the website or how to donate, but how to thank specific users for answering questions

Comment: @wcarhart upvote/accept. Maybe put a bounty to reward an existing answer.

Comment: @wcarhart please read the [first answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269683/4751173) to that question, or alternatively, the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), under the caption 'Pay it forward'.

Comment: *There is always the option of privately messaging a user who has answered your question to thank him or her* but that is not a functionality the site provides ...

Comment: @rene I fixed the incorrect information, my mistake. However, I have reviewed the question you tagged as the duplicate, and after my edits I feel I have shown that this question is not a duplicate, because I am asking how to thank users, not the service

Comment: The website, the service, their users. I don't see much of a difference and the answer will literally be the same.

Comment: @rene I respectfully disagree. The service, which is more of a company or website, is very different from individual people who take time to answer questions

Comment: Fair point, fixed that on the dupe target but if you still disagree, you can click reopen under your question to bring it for the eyes of reviewers.

Comment: @rene no, the OP here can't vote to reopen, it needs [250 reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes). (Only course of action is flagging.)

Comment: You wouldn't believe how many people ask a question and then never come back to reply to comments, improve the question, upvote, accept or give any kind of feedback about answers. Doing (some of) these things shows that you appreciate the effort other users put into answering your question; a personal thank you note isn't necessary (unless maybe as part of a comment about how a specific part of an answer was particularly helpful).

Comment: @rene I was reviewing this question, and I saw that you edited the target duplicate just to argue your point, and then you edited it back to the original once you'd marked this question as a duplicate. That doesn't seem to be a helpful strategy for answering questions, and frankly is a bit disrespectful to take advantage of users who are new to the site/don't have enough rep to oppose you.

Comment: @ThePickleTickler Sorry that you perceived it that way. You made a case that the duplicate I choose to use mu dupe hammer wasn't appropriate in your case, so I took that in consideration and decided to edit the target to cover your case and offering you to re-open if you still disagreed. Then ShadowWizard made me aware that you can't re-open your self so I decided to use my re-open vote because you would not be able to restart the re-open process and if you attempt to edit your question to get it re-opened it would probably fail.

Comment: @rene Alright, my misunderstanding. Thanks for the help.

Comment: But as I did re-open my edit in the dupe target became unneeded so I rolled back that edit and wrote an answer that I made community wiki so it would not count for any  badges or any other gain I could have from my answer. I did that because I already had so much involvement in this question but I believe it needed an answer. If that is considered as opposing then I apologize once more. I only tried to be helpful and receptive for your feedback.

Comment: Stack Overflow has now added a "Thanks" button below the upvote/downvote buttons. https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/06/17/saying-thanks-testing-a-new-reactions-feature/ . BTW, I also agree this question is different than the ["duplicate"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269681/how-can-i-thank-this-website) linked above.

Comment: I think the "thanks" button is (thankfully) gone from the public site now, though the "feature" still lives on in the private "Stack Overflow for Teams" sites.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I'll bring in the answer from [Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17886/158100) as posted on MSE, pointed out by [ShadowWizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/447356/shadow-wizard)

> First of all, anyone posting here with the idea that they should be personally thanked for every answer they provide is going to be very disappointed.
>
> If you *really* want to thank someone for a good answer, then you'll perhaps take the time to go through one of *their* questions and provide a good answer for some programming question *they* have.
>
> Alternately, **just "pay it forward" and answer another programmer's question**. That's really what it's all about.

I'll add my personal note: Stack Overflow is not a social network. In that sense, over-exaggerated (and a bit of humor), I don't care about users (not literally, I still have to [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)), we care about good posts. You won't find functions here to PM users. The closest you can get is chat, but that still isn't private.

Comment: "we don't care about users"? Perhaps that should be rephrased a little.

Comment: @TravisJ No, but if what I mean goes undetected it misses the effect. So now I put everything in that casual readers might need.

Comment: A quote: "[Stack Overflow is generally unconcerned with the feelings of people. We care about quality of questions and answers. If there's something irrelevant in a question, get rid of it. Religious sentiments on Stack Overflow are irrelevant, unless you're proclaiming Jon Skeet as your god, praise be his name.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321360/what-does-bh-mean-in-this-question?cb=1#comment335717_321467)"

Comment: I am so honoured to be quoted!

Answer (score 22):

As someone that answers a lot of questions, yes, an accept is great.  Not all askers take the trouble to do that.

A comment from the OP on an answer can be interesting if they say something like "*this is great, it runs 5 times faster than my first attempt*".

Or "*that extra section about topic xyz was really useful, I hadn't even thought of that*".  (I tend to write long answers that do more than just answer the OP's direct / specific question, and it's nice to hear when the extra time I spent rambling about interesting related stuff was actually appreciated.)  Or even a more generic "*wow, this is more detail than I was expecting*" comment will make me feel good about the time I put into writing that answer.  It's rewarding to know that people actually read those long answers I write.  This obviously only applies to long answers where that's the case.

I sometimes get comments like "*this was the best answer in the history of the known universe*" (maybe a small exaggeration here :), and I'm sometimes tempted to upvote them myself. :P  Especially if the comment comes from another active SO user that I know (from other comments/answers) knows what they're talking about.  This goes double if the comment points out something *specific* that my answer explains well, rather than just generic praise.

---

But generic "thank you, that solved my problem" comments from the OP, especially on a question that wasn't very interesting (e.g. a simple newbie error, or especially a debugging-help question which probably has very low future value), then my reaction can be as negative as "**why did they waste my time with a notification to come and read this comment** after I already spent more time than they deserve answering their lame question".  This is multiplied by 1000% if they didn't accept my answer.  The level of annoyance for a useless comment also depends on my perception of the OP's competence (including spellcheck / style as well as what they misunderstood or were unable to debug or search).

Of course, I welcome a comment that helps me clarify my answer for the OP and future readers.  Maybe there was one part of the explanation that I didn't go into enough detail about, or an editing error left something unclear.

---

**If you don't have anything interesting to say along with the "thank you", just don't**.  I already assume that my answers solve the OP's problem or confusion and that they're happy I answered (unless I know my answer was only a partial solution).  Getting a check-mark confirms that.

---

That sounds really egotistical when I put it that way (some of which was for comedic effect), but I hang out in tags where I know enough to post solid answers.  It's not surprising that an expert can be confident they've given a good answer to most questions (if they take the time to write one).  I don't think it's that egotistical to be confident in my answers, especially after hanging around on SO for a while and getting lots of helpful and positive feedback on previous answers.

---

**Another thing an OP can do that I really appreciate is to edit their question to improve it** and make it more useful to future readers after seeing what the right answer is.  It makes me happy that I helped out someone who cares enough about SO to put in some extra effort and make it a better place.

If there was some long rambling section that turned out to be irrelevant, it's great when they tidy that up.  (Although it's *not* good when they edit a summary of the answer into the question.  Don't do that.)  It's also not good to remove too much of the original wording they used to describe the problem, because future searchers might guess the same thing if they don't know the correct terminology.

I do clean up questions fairly often, but I really appreciate it when the OP manages to do something useful in that direction.

Comment: With a friendly GitHub/GitLab emoticon marker, we could at least let the person who answered know we at least read their answer, without having to declare what we formally think about their answer.

Answer (score 10):

Aside from upvoting and accepting the answer that works, [you can state that "one of the answers is exemplary and is worth an additional bounty".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)