# How do I thank users who improve my answers?

Tags: support, edits

I would really like to find out a way to thank people who improve my answers. I tried looking at their profile but I could not find a private message button or something akin to that.

Comment: Note that if the editor has under 2K rep then they already earned +2 by getting the edit approved.

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish in the greater scheme of things by thanking them?

Comment: Hope to accomplish? Nothing. It is just in my nature to thank people for something that they do in my interest, and in this regard, for the SO community. :)

Comment: If it's an edit from "Jonathan", then add @Jonathan in a comment of your answer and he'll be notified.

Comment: @Cœur But those comments will be deleted... And besides it is just adding more work for the mods. See AlexeiLevenkov's comment on the answer.

Comment: @Raja Why will such comments get deleted? Are they rude?

Comment: @10Rep I request you to please refer to the comments by Alexei Levenkov and Cody Gray in ale's answer. My bad, I should have given more reference in my previous comment.

Comment: @Raja But **why** do they need to be removed?

Comment: @10Rep They are not rude. They are considered noise. They do not add value to Stack Overflow. They don't add value to someone else that need an answer. They're a personal interaction between two individuals. Nothing about the problem/solution can be learned from it. It's kind of like wikipedia. You don't land on a page and then first read: I'd like to thank every reader for reading this page :)

Comment: @Scratte So what you are saying is since SO questions are seen by people who have the same question as the poster, you shouldn't add thank you comments. Ok then!

Comment: @10Rep See [Why are fellow users removing thank-you's from my questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328379/why-are-fellow-users-removing-thank-yous-from-my-questions). It's linked from the [FAQ index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251225). It's not **because** isn't seen by other people, but because the site wants to remain formal, though with the new thank-you-button, the borders are somewhat blurry now.

Comment: @Scratte Yes, that's what I mean. The site is meant to be formal and informative, so no thank you's. Got it.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

There's no private-messaging service on Stack Exchange.

If you want to thank the people who have improved your answers, *pay it forward* by fixing other people's posts. Better, learn from these changes and make your own posts better from the get-go.

You *could* @mention them in a comment.  However, such comments will be flagged and deleted.

Comment: I'd recommend against adding "thank you" comments - I can't see much positive value, but plenty of negative - filling out inboxes with pointless notifications and adding extra work to moderators to deal with removing such comments when they are appropriately flagged for removal.

Comment: Yeah...please don't leave "thank you for editing" comments. That just means I have to go around cleaning them up. :-( Editors assume you appreciate their efforts, that's why they do it. Paying it forward is great. That's what keeps the site going.

Answer (score 40):

Interaction on Stack Overflow is oftentimes supposed to be non-personal. Speaking for myself, off-site, when people help me, I thank them to acknowledge and value what they did for me. Considering that SO is supposed to be non-personal (hence why many oppose the new CoC), improvements that people make to your content, are made for the greater good, and the benefit for all of SO. People that improve your answers, do it as their contribution to the repository that SO is. Therefore, there is no need to thank them, as it was not personal, and not targeted at anyone. Your appreciation should rather come as other contributions to SO. If your answer was helpful, you already did contribute.

[Rene and Jeff write it well](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/330570/7395227)