# How to say "Thank you" if someone edited (and improved) my answer/question?

Tags: discussion

Particular case. User "a_horse_with_no_name" (a PostgreSQL expert) improved my answer. I want to say "thank you" for this edit. See https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24046643/3

Is there a way to do so?

On GitHub there are buttons for thumb up, love, happy, etc.

Maybe a less childish version would be nice. Or more explicit feedback would be better. A smile can mean so many things and I personally think a sentence says much more. But this is only an implementation detail. First there needs to be agreement if this is wanted.

This question was marked as duplicated. Big fun: The question which was given, is a a duplicate, too.

My question is not a vague question to say "thank you" somewhere/everywhere/nowhere. It is focused on exactly one place: edits of questions/answers.

**update**

There seem to be a lot of people who do not want to say or hear "thank you". That's ok. But on the other hand I like to hear and say it. And I guess a lot of other people feel like me. Yes, I understand that comments are not good for this. But .... is there no third way beyond yes/not. A solution no one thought about before?

Comment: [Pay it forward by helping others](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/330562/5894241).

Comment: @NisargShah: That's about answers. You can't "upvote" edits.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yup, I had seen that. But the answer applies to this question as well. I think there is an exact dupe somewhere (about edits) with the same answer, but I can't find it ATM.

Comment: On MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11226/etiquette-for-thanking-an-editor

Comment: It looks like that there are far more people who like to work in a bureaucratic way (down-voting, finding duplicates), then to think in creative way how to improve the site. This is not a rant, this is just my personal impression. I am deeply relax - have a nice day :-)

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11231/218388) summarises my opinions towards the whole subject really well.

Comment: @Script47 just for the records, I added a this comment there: Yes, you are right. Too many "thank you" in comments are annoying. On the other hand I like the thumb-up and heart icons which github has. There you see the number of thanks, and if you are curious you can look who thanked you.

Comment: We have thumbs-up icons: they look like triangles, and we use them for voting. We also have thumbs-down. No, obviously you can't vote on edits, but that's the whole point.

Comment: @CodyGray yes, you are right. The triangles exist. AFAIK it's impossible to make the number next to the triangle (count of upvotes) to a clickable hyperlink.

Comment: If you are helped by a horse, find his/her field and offer a sugar cube.

Comment: @guettli *"It looks like that there are far more people who like to work in a bureaucratic way"*, if you refer to people you see posting on meta, probably yes. Most of us here use the site the way the site intends us to use it, focusing on the content and not on the users. However the meta denizens are only a small percentage of the total user base, and there absolutely not enough people do the good and important tasks such as voting honestly and optimising content such as by linking duplicates.

Comment: Well you can send them a comment by `@username` them. But beware, these comments adds noise to the site, so please don’t start sending thank you’s to everyone, the mods wont appreciate it.  But if you still want to send the thank you, just delete the comment afterwards, after you think they saw it (or an hour has past). So there’s no need to make the mods delete it for you.

Comment: @abccd creating a comment and deleting it later could work. But please tell me: Do you think this is a good solution. Would you do this?

Comment: why not? personally I don't care about comments exchanging pleasantries but if there are people that will spend their time flagging these it saves some moderator time.

Answer (score 2):

You *could* @mention users that edited a question / answer.

However, comments like *"Thanks for the edit"* are pretty noisy. **Better not** start thanking everyone for every small edit they make.

Comment: Yes, you are right. On the other hand, if someone says "thank you" to the things I do, that's like music to my ears.

Comment: Can we @mention user who edit our post if he/she not leaving any comments under our post ?

Comment: Yes @JohnJoe. Although their name won't appear when you start typing an `@`, They will get a notification.

Comment: Please don't do this. These comments will just get flagged, and they're more work for me and other moderators to clean up. We have better things we could be doing.

Comment: @CodyGray: Yea, I slightly tweaked the answer to lean towards "don't"

Comment: If you're advocating *don't* doesn't this answer become redundant because of its contradictory nature (*You could[...]* then ***Better not [...]***)?

Comment: @Script47: _"Could"_ means it's "Possible", followed by the advice not to do it.

Comment: Not to get in to a whole debate regarding this, but surely this would be better suited as a comment?

Comment: "Better not" is an answer by itself. The added information that editors are @mention-able doesn't make this a comment.