# Is showing gratitude to something that helped can be considered as a spam?

Tags: support, spam

I answered today this question: 
[Create a button that accepts .PNG images as Glyph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46758140/create-a-button-that-accepts-png-images-as-glyph/46796879#46796879)

I was wondering if adding this paragraph would make the answer look like a spam.

**Paragraph:**

> **Note:** This work is based on the [FlatStyle](https://sourceforge.net/projects/flatstyle/) component set. it
>   helped me a lot and it was one of the bases of component writing for
>   me. Check it out.
>
> This is a non official version compatible with Delphi 10 Seattle (I
>   made the change so use it on your own risk).

I would like to add that I'm not one of the developers of this set and I have no relation what so ever with this set. So would this be considered as spam?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to say thank you on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330562/where-to-say-thank-you-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I'm not saying thank you to the developer of this set. I'm recommending its product

Comment: If you read the answer provided there, you will note that it's also applicable: StackOverflow is not a place for thanks, not to people who answer your questions, not to people that develop great software, and not to the people who created this site. You can and should note attribution, however.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would certainly look like spam, at least to me -- one common tactic used by spammers is "use [this], it worked so well for me and I'm sure it'll help for you". Instead, be specific! Don't say "this is good", say "this has a bunch of useful features, like [list here], and handles [edge case] in a really nice way -- [description]". If you give concrete evidence, it sounds a lot less like spam than it does if you just say "it's great".

If this was just a paragraph tacked on to the end of an answer that's otherwise complete, even without it, it wouldn't be as spammy. At the same time, if you've got specific props to give, that's probably more effective than just a generic "this is great".

And, of course, make sure you [aren't a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion), like the other answer says.

Answer (score 6):

As long as it answers the question and you disclose your affiliation (or, in this case, your lack thereof) then it isn't spam.

See also: [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)