# Does Stack Exchange take donations?

Tags: discussion

Does Stack Exchange or Stack Overflow take donations from people?

I've always wondered that :)

I've never seen any sort of fundraising campaign going on, though ...

Comment: .for some charity organisations you mean?

Comment: @SurajRao - No, I meant donate money *to* Stack Exchange, to help them stay in business, pay for operational costs, etc.

Comment: @SurajRao if Wikipedia asks us for $3, why not SE ask us for something similar?  Just curious :)

Comment: Well.. Wikipedia is AFAIK a non profit.. SE has a different business model

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/330562, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269681

Comment: Send more money to Joel Spolsky - a multi-millionaire...why on earth?

Comment: If you really want to contribute to what makes this website work, donate to an expert contributor. Y'know, not the healthy Silicon Valley business, but one of the people giving their time to solve your problems for you, for free. Although not Jon Skeet. He already has enough SO branded t-shirts and mugs to pay college tuition for 20,000 children ^_^

Comment: A case of "shut up and take my money" huh

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yeah, I was thinking of a "Dollars for Rep" contribution to an expert contributor, using a factor of 1, for simplicity.  Hypothetically, you would get $200,000 ish USD from me, but where would I send it to ensure you rightfully get the money?  If it sits with Joel Spolsky, then as you said, it wouldn't reward the contributors that make this site great.  Maybe Stack Overflow has like an "Office for Giving", like a university would have ... 

Comment: @D.Hutchinson Well, the idea of getting paid for your contributions is antithetical to what this website is all about, so it's never going to be a feature. Some people do put "donate" links on their profile and you're free to use those of course. Otherwise, you're encouraged to "pay it forward" by making positive contributions yourself.

Comment: @D.Hutchinson: But hey don't let me stop you from sending me US$263,577 if you really want ;)

Answer (score 26):

Wikipedia is a nonprofit, Stack Overflow is for-profit and [has even taken VC money](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/05/04/announcing-our-series-a/). There's no way to just send SE money. It'd probably be a tax headache.

If you're over 200 rep, you could [opt out of reduced advertising](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) (ideally if you're actually interested in the ads). Using Careers to look for (or post!) jobs is probably also helpful.

Comment: So, can we *invest* in SE?

Answer (score 13):

> I've never seen any sort of fundraising campaign going on, though ...

Well, even if you have > 200 rep, you see at least *some* adverts. And those are a fundraising activity. :-)

That said: SE does indeed accept donations —of **time**, asking and (particularly) answering questions, moderating the site, etc. Without those donations, the site would very quickly cease to exist. Time is probably the most valuable thing on Earth, so...

Comment: Time... flies. Time... cures all ills. Time... rosemary and.... #cheersjohncrichton

Comment: Time flies like an arrow; fruit flies like a banana.

Comment: Sometimes, TJ, one donates money better than they could donate their time, ya know?   there's nothing inherently "wrong" with deferring to the subject matter experts on SO and instead contribute in other ways.  I encourage SO / Stack Exchange to consider having those conversations with the communities, especially if the question has never been asked before  @LightnessRacesInOrbit

Comment: @D.Hutchinson: *"there's nothing inherently "wrong" with deferring to the subject matter experts on SO and instead contribute in other ways"* Absolutely, and if you don't want to donate your time, that's fine. It's a donation after all. :-) I wouldn't worry about giving them money, though.